# Should I upgrade my Mid 2009 MBP 15 2.8 to MBPr 13?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, thunderbolt, hdmi, display

I code on eclipse and XCode on my Mid 2009 MBP 15 inch 2.8 ghz works very good. (very good = acceptable compile times and almost no occasional freezes. You don't get because of the slowness percentage) (It is also in very good physical condition)

I will be taking out my computer with me to meet a group of friends for a week to work on projects, brainstorm, etc.. I see this (as an excuse) opportunity to refresh my macbookpro (even though technically I am cool with it).

Do you think that I have to upgrade my device to MBPr 13 inch (256gb default option)?

My device does not have usb3 ports, retina screen, solid-state disk, thunderbolt, hdmi out(I use minidisplay to hdmi converter(no-audio)).

Do you think that I miss things? Like... may my working environment be less inspiring? (:

Comment: Please tell me the reason for -1 :-/

Comment: My guess is the vote is expressing a long held stack exchange preference to not have hardware shopping questions. (Or that you have asked twice what people think which makes some people miss the requirements you listed.) You could improve this by quantifying how changing something that already works very good would make sense for spending more money.

Comment: My guess would be it's probably because, generally speaking, asking questions where the answers will be opinion based are frowned upon. Anyway, IMO you should compare all the specifications and then make the decision to buy a new computer all on your own regardless of what anyone has say.

Comment: @user3439894 Well said. I've added a "general opinion" answer since this question isn't the one we expected with lots of specifics. It's also much better than the general shopping questions that we close immediately for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to read between the lines, you are indirectly asking if the physical size and resolution of the 13 inch retina Mac is equal to or better than your existing 15 inch model.

It's clear that everything is faster on the new models. Heck, the new 2015 MacBook would probably run every workload and benchmark faster than any 2009 Mac including the Mac Pro of that vintage.

I would encourage you to refresh now. It's always the best time to buy Apple products when a new one is announced.

1. You know exactly what the latest bump is and can choose to get "last year's model" on sale from Apple or for a very good price used or buy the latest.
2. Between new and refurbished, you probably have 4 (or 6) price points instead of the 2 you normally get buying new from Apple.

As to the specifics of your "upgrade" - it's a great time to upgrade.

1. Intel CPU are massively more efficient and powerful from 2009 to 2015
2. USB is massively better - both in absolute terms and that Macs from 2009 had less optimal drivers for them IMO.
3. SSD storage is far better than HDD for almost every use case. Not only are you getting that jump, the the SSD in 2014/2015 are far better than 2012 and earlier in terms of performance and $/perf.
4. Retina screens are excellent for cases where you have lots of elements (Xcode and text) as well as far more pleasing than LCD from 2009 era.
5. You get a new Mac after 5 years

All of the above reasons would make your work environment much more inspiring. Especially if you can sell your old Mac or donate it and afford the new one.

Comment: Very good points! +1

Comment: Thank you so much for your constructive and positive approach to my question. I am aware that stackexchange does not like questions close to full-opinion-based, but really there are no better platform for me to ask this question. So I risked it (: Finally, what do you think about 13 inch? I know it is small but will I really feel claustrophobic while programming on-the-go?

Comment: You're asking the wrong person. I recently traded in my 13 inch retina (i've had that line since Apple launched it for programming on the go) for the even smaller 12 inch MacBook. I use mission control heavily and full screen apps so even a mini iPad can't keep me from doing work. It's often not the size of your screen, but how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I Know that i am late but if you still have the macbook pro 15 inch 2009 you should put an ssd (solid state drive) in it and 8gb of ram. my friend just got a 2015 macbook air and mine is almost as fast as his. + those macbook pros are really expensive. trust me if you haven't upgraded it yet, you should try it as it is a huge improvement from the hdd (hard disk drive). and if you use a lot of cd's you won't have to connect an external drive every time your need to use it. plus the screen is a 1440 x 900 the new screens are 2560 by 1600 it isn't that much of a difference really they make it seem better than it really is. Also the bigger screen means more screen real estate which means bigger apps open at the same time. I really suggest you try this first before upgrading (if u haven't yet) and if you still think you need an upgrade, go for it.